# Rails where with join, but return object of parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

Suppose I have a class that represents a list of movies, belonging to a user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :movie_list
end

class MovieList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :movie_list_movie_relationships
    has_many :movies, :through => :movie_list_movie_relationships
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movie_list_movie_relationships
    has_many :movie_lists, :through => :movie_list_movie_relationships
end

class MovieListMovieRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
    belongs_to :movie_list
end
```

Is there any way to have a method on MovieList that returns a MovieList containing only movies with, for example, a specific release year.  I want something like:

```
class MovieList < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    def for_year year
        movies.where(:year => year)
    end
end
```

EXCEPT that I want the result to be a MovieList itself, whereas this returns an array of Movies.  So I could do, for example:

```
list = User.first.movie_list.for_year(1999)
list.id # would give the id of the MovieList = User.first.movie_list.id
list.movies.first.id # would give the id of the first movie in list
```

I have a feeling that I'm either a) faced with this problem because my design is bad, and it would be great if someone could explain how I *should* design this, or b) asking for something relatively mundane but I just don't know the right terminology.

Thanks!

**Edit**

I have specific reasons for wanting a `MovieList` and not an array of `Movie`s.  For one, I've written the question with `User has_one :movie_list` but in reality a `User has_many :movie_lists` (e.g., "Movies I have on DVD", "Movies I want to see", etc).  That's why I don't just use a simple join between `User` and `Movie`.  I want a `MovieList` because I want the `id` of the list to get passed around to make it easy to add a movie to a specific list; I have a `MovieListMovieRelationshipController`.  I think what I'm going to end up having to do is fetch the movies as an array and just pass around the list id manually.

**Edit 2**

Here's what I ended up doing, as per @normalocity and the ensuing comments.  Any further comments/suggestions are appreciated :)

```
class MovieList
    ...
    def limit_to_year year
        new_list = MovieList.new(self.attributes)
        new_list.id = self.id
        new_list.movies = []

        limited_movies = movies.where(:year => year)
        new_list.movies = limited_movies
        return new_list
    end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that MovieList isn't an array of Movies, and it shouldn't be. If you want an array of Movies, then you have to get Movie objects, not a MovieList object. I have two questions: 1) Why do you want the `for_year` method to return a `MovieList`? 2) Why have `MovieList` at all? Why not just a many-to-many association between `User` and `Movie`, with something like class `UserMovie` in between? In other words, your `MovieList` is a join model to a join model, which is generally bad design, unless you have an important attribute on `MovieList` that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I don't want MovieList to be an array of Movies.  Re: 1) MovieList has some other properties that I want. 2) Because there can be more than one type of list.  Going with the movie analog: "Movies I have on DVD", "Movies I have on BluRay", "Movies I want to see in the theatre".  I wrote it as User :has_one movie_list to simplify the question.  It's actually :has_many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're hoping for directly, no, but it's simple enough to create an empty `MovieList`, and then add the array of movies from your `for_year` method to the new `MovieList`. You can even make the query for the array of associated `Movie` objects faster/simpler via a `named_scope`.

- Create a [named scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) to get all Movies from a specific year:

In `Movie` class:

```
named_scope :for_year, lambda { |year| {:conditions => ["year = ?", year]} }
```

Now, every time you call `Movie.for_year("1945")` you get back an array of Movie objects from that year.

Then...

- Create a new `MovieList` (that belongs to NO user), and add the results from #1 to the list

This might work:
`movies1945 = MovieList.create(:movies => Movie.for_year("1945")`

If it doesn't work, you might have to split up the creation of the new `MovieList` object, and the assignment of values to the `Movie` collection.

If you need to distinguish between a simple list of Movies (what's the difference between that and an Array, I don't know, but if that distinction is necessary), and the `Movies` that a particular user has in their collection, then you could separate your classes into `MovieList` (just a list of movies) and a `Collection` (the movies that a given user has).

If you don't need that, then the 1945 movie list could either have a `nil` user, or (say your web site is called [imdb.com](http://imdb.com)) you could create a dummy user account called `"imdb"`, and have the list belong to that user.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think I just can't do what I want.  What I wanted was for `User.first.movie_list.for_year(1999)` to have the same `id` as `User.first.movie_list` - essentially to act like the same object but have only some of the actual `movies`.  But if they have the same `id`, then they should **be** the same object, so I think maybe I'm asking for a no-no.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work that way, because what you're really trying to do get is a list of `Movie` objects from a given year, which is an array, not a `MovieList` object. You could, however, with the named_scope shown above do: `User.first.movies.for_year(1999)`, which returns an array of `Movie` objects, that belong to that user AND ALSO are in the specified year. But that is still just an array of `Movie` objects. My guess is that you *think* you want a `MovieList` object, when really an array of `Movie` objects will serve your purpose.

Comment: I'll try to edit my question to clarify.  I have a reason for wanting a MovieList and not an array of Movies.

Comment: I see the thing about multiple lists. I would still say the simplest thing to do would be to create an empty MovieList (`MovieList.new`) and then append the `Movie` objects that you find from your queries to the `MovieList.movies` collection and be done with it. Regardless of how you implement it, there will be an interim step of Movies being in an array at some point, before they are added to the `MovieList` object. I don't think you're design is incorrect - I think you're just trying to skip a step that (a) is no big deal and (b) just has to happen.